# Display message on screen of iframe src is empty

Tags: html, jquery, css, django, ajax

I want to display a message "Please click on a match to get started" when there is no match link clicked. i.e. the iframe is without an src. I am using django at the backend. Here is my html:

```
  </form><br>
      {% for match in all_matches %}
      <li style="list-style:none; text-align: center"><a style="padding: 6px 8px 6px 16px;text-decoration: none;font-size: 18px;color: #ffffff;display: block;" href="{{match.url}}" target="iframe1">{{match.name}}</a></li>
      <hr class="new1">
      {% endfor %}
    </div>

  <div class="col-sm-9 col-xs-9 col-md-9 col-lg-9" id="frameContainer">

  <iframe name="iframe1" id="fr" style="display: block;" width=100% height=100% frameborder="0" allowFullScreen="true"></iframe>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably the simplest way to do this is to have a static HTML file as the initial iframe source, which contains the message.